# run rspec while running test/unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In our current applications we only run Test::Unit tests. So we do `rake test` and it runs all the tests under test.
I'm adding a rspec directory as well and I want the rspecs to run when I do `rake test` instead of manually also doing `rspec spec`.

Any idea how to combine both under `rake test`?

We have our `TestTask` under the gems for example `vendor/gems/shoulda-2.10.3/Rakefile:Rake::TestTask.new do |t| ...`

and in `application.rb` we have

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :shoulda
  g.fallbacks[:shoulda] = :test_unit
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line in the Rakefile, It will Run the `spec` and `test` task, when you execute the `rake test`

```
task :test => :spec
```

Answer (score 1):

RSpec can actually run your Test::Unit cases for you, just `require 'spec/test/unit'`